# Correct use of commas

Tags: grammar

Have I used commas correctly in this sentence please? I'm not sure if they are required after the "and".

"The boy grew, and grew, and grew, into a magical boy named Kevin, who was the height and size of a tree".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, no, they are not required. However, as "pause commas" to aid reading, then they can be justified.